# Question on poset of positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, order-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a subset of the partially ordered set (poset) of $n\times n$ positive semi-definite matrices. I know that $\inf \Omega\in \bar{\Omega}$, where $\bar{\Omega}$ denotes the closure of $\Omega.$

If $\inf \Omega=X$, can I say that

\begin{array}{ll} \text{inf} & \operatorname{trace}(Y'\Omega Y)=\operatorname{trace}(Y'XY)?\\ \Omega\end{array}

I think trace is monotone increasing on the cone of positive definite matrices, it should hold?

Comment: Is $\Omega$ such that $\inf \Omega$ uniquely exists? What is $Y$? An arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: yes, such $\inf\Omega$ uniquely exists. $Y$ is an arbitrary matrix, not necessary square

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by $\operatorname{trace}(Y'\Omega Y)$, since $\Omega$ is a set, not a matrix.

Comment: @BenGrossmann we want to find an element of this set, that makes the above trace minimal. I want to know if that element is $X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are trying to ask the following:

> If there exists an $X \in \bar \Omega$ such that $X \preceq Z$ (Loewner order) for all $Z \in \Omega$, then does it necessarily hold that
> $$
> \inf_{Z \in \Omega} \operatorname{trace}(Y'ZY) = \operatorname{trace}(Y'XY)?
> $$

The answer to this is yes. In particular, if such an $X$ exists, then for all $Z \in \Omega$, we have
$$
\operatorname{trace}(Y'ZY) = 
\operatorname{trace}(Y'(Z - X)Y) + \operatorname{trace}(Y'XY) \geq 
\operatorname{trace}(Y'XY).
$$

Comment: yes, thanks for the help